# How to Insert Select every with TOP() clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

these are my table,

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8087/1

What i'm trying to achieve is insert into another new table by selecting from Tbl2 and CustTable.

E.g:

```
INSERT INTO tbl3
SELECT TOP(SELECT Counter FROM Tbl2) a.name, a.amount FROM custTable a
INNER JOIN Tbl2 b ON a.custId = b.custid
```

I want to insert X number of ROW base on CustId's [Counter].
It's not working because Subquery returned more than 1 value.

how can i fix the query in TOP()?

Comment: I might have not understood the problem but for the SQL error you need some `aggregate function` in select query like `SELECT TOP(SELECT COUNT(Counter) FROM Tbl2) a.name, a.amount FROM custTable a INNER JOIN Tbl2 b ON a.custId = b.custid`

Comment: The Counter is already the (COUNT). I just need to select the Counter of each CustId and put it in TOP().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Windowing functions to do rank the rows by customer, and then filter by the counter:

```
WITH cte as
(
  SELECT a.Name, a.Amount, b.Counter, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.CustID ORDER BY a.Amount DESC) AS RN
  FROM custTable a
  INNER JOIN Tbl2 b ON a.custId = b.custid  
)
SELECT cte.name, cte.amount 
INTO tbl3
FROM cte
WHERE cte.rn <= Counter;
```

You'll need to choose an ORDER on each customer to determine 'which' of the TOP records get included (I've assumed you want the top amounts here)

I've also used `SELECT ... INTO` to create table 3 on the fly, but you can `INSERT INTO` if it is already created.

[Updated your SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8087/18)

Comment: Looks good, i will try it out at my side. But mind to explain a little bit more on how your solution work? Thanks!

Comment: Your requirement is to limit the number of rows not overall (which is the use case for `TOP`), but on a per-Cust id 'grouping'. This makes the problem well suited to windowing functions, where we add an arbitrary `ranking` to the records for each customer. We can then compare this ranking to the variable 'Counter' stored in `TblB` and apply a normal `WHERE` filter to include the correct number of rows per custid.